# Kibana crashing after my computer went to sleep

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am running Kibana Version 8.8.1 and Elasticsearch Version 8.8.1 on my MacBook Pro M2. Upon initial configuration and installation of the Elk stack with home-brew, I was able to access the Kibana Dev console and write queries and was also able to use a python client for writing queries. But after my MacBook went to sleep mode, I am getting errors from Kibana. I use cURL to check out if Elasticsearch was up and running and get the following success message:

```
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
{
  "name" : "WM-xxxxxxx",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "oEn7xc4xxxxxxxxcGdQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.8.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "f8edfxxxxxa429b6477927xxxxxxx29521xx05e",
    "build_date" : "2023-06-05T21:32:25.188464208Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Note: I have replaced some of the values with X's for privacy reasons.

When I try to run Kibana in a separate terminal window, I get the following error:

```
[2023-06-26T10:47:45.686+05:30][WARN ][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Found browser binary checksum for darwin/x64 in /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/chromium/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium is MISSING but 9960dd00ab27b4e9ee1455692bb65701 was expected. Re-installing... 
[2023-06-26T10:47:45.698+05:30][WARN ][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Browser archive checksum for darwin/x64 is d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e but 2ce969500158dd98e3ad4502dbb6b13c was expected. [2023-06-26T10:47:45.698+05:30][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Downloading https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/1121448/chrome-mac.zip to /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/.chromium/x64/chrome-mac.zip 
[2023-06-26T10:47:45.716+05:30][ERROR][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND commondatastorage.googleapis.com at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26) at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) 
[2023-06-26T10:47:45.716+05:30][ERROR][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Error: Failed to download https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/1121448/chrome-mac.zip: Error: Unable to download https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/1121448/chrome-mac.zip: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND commondatastorage.googleapis.com at download (/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/server/browsers/download/index.js:61:11) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at install (/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/server/browsers/install.js:43:5) at async Promise.all (index 1) at /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/server/plugin.js:44:36 
[2023-06-26T10:47:45.718+05:30][ERROR][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Error: Error installing browsers, binary checksums incorrect for [x64/darwin] at install (/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/server/browsers/install.js:54:19) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at async Promise.all (index 1) at /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/server/plugin.js:44:36 
[2023-06-26T10:47:45.718+05:30][ERROR][plugins.screenshotting] Error in screenshotting setup, it may not function properly.
[2023-06-26T10:47:45.718+05:30][ERROR][plugins.screenshotting] Error: Error installing browsers, binary checksums incorrect for [x64/darwin] at install (/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/server/browsers/install.js:54:19) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at async Promise.all (index 1) at /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/elastic/kibana-8.8.1/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/server/plugin.js:44:36
```

I have disabled the default gatekeeping functions of MacBook to run Kibana.

**Note: Kibana and Elasticsearch were up and running earlier and I was able to use the dev console as well as Python client earlier. Kibana has crashed after the laptop went to sleep.**

After Kibana has crashed, I went to the localhost URL obtained from the earlier session and now I get the following error message:

```
Kibana server is not ready yet.
```

Comment: Note: I haven't made any changes to any of the .yml files and am running on completely default settings.

Comment: As your error message says issue must be related to `.chromium` . I don't know what is it exactly, but try to find that and delete them. After that try to restart the ELK stack